# Vendo Histórico de consultas no Sql Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando recuperar consultas que realizei no Sql Server Management Studio 2014, sei que existe uma funcionalidade de simples histórico no Heidi Sql, gostaria de saber se no Sql Server Management Studio 2014 existe a mesma funcionalidade.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa habilitar o *recover* nas configurações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Legal, agora ele está guardando o histórico, como eu faço para ver as consultas, uma vez que ele está guardando o histórico?

Comment: Esta resposta não responde à pergunta. O camarada quer saber como visualizar o histórico, o rapaz só respondeu como habilitar a recuperação do histórico.